# connecting two java frame

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, multiple-instances

Actually I am New to java I want to know how to link two frames. I made two different java files, which looks simple. But I am unable to solve it till now. It should open the welcome frame by clicking Next Button in Enter.java. Can anybody help me?

Here is my code:

```
Enter.java

import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Enter extends JFrame {

public Enter() {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 20));

add(new JLabel("Name"));
add(new JTextField(8));
add(new JLabel("Address"));
add(new JTextField(15));
add(new JLabel("Surname"));
add(new JTextField(8));
add(new JLabel("Phone"));
add(new JTextField(8));
add(new JButton("Next"));
}


/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Enter myProg = new Enter();
myProg.setTitle("Ceng 344 - Lab 7");
myProg.setSize(450, 400);
myProg.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
myProg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
myProg.setVisible(true);
}

}

Welcome.java
 import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class welcome extends JFrame {

public welcome() {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 20));

add(new JLabel("Welcome"));
}


/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
welcome myProg = new welcome();
myProg.setTitle("Ceng 344 - Lab 7");
myProg.setSize(450, 400);
myProg.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
myProg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
myProg.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call the `Welcome` Frame from the `Next` Button, so that you can add the action to this button.

Try this:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main() {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 20));

        add(new JLabel("Name"));
        add(new JTextField(8));
        add(new JLabel("Address"));
        add(new JTextField(15));
        add(new JLabel("Surname"));
        add(new JTextField(8));
        add(new JLabel("Phone"));
        add(new JTextField(8));
        JButton next = new JButton("Next");
        add(next);
        next.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                NextActionPerformed(evt);
            }

            private void NextActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                welcome myProg = new welcome();
                myProg.setTitle("Ceng 344 - Lab 7");
                myProg.setSize(450, 400);
                myProg.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                myProg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                myProg.setVisible(true);
            }
        });



    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Main myProg = new Main();
        myProg.setTitle("Ceng 344 - Lab 7");
        myProg.setSize(450, 400);
        myProg.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        myProg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myProg.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class welcome extends JFrame {

    public welcome() {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 20));
        add(new JLabel("Welcome"));
    }
    /**
     * @param args
     */
}
```

i remove the Welcome's Main class , and add it's content to the **NextActionPerformed** method

Comment: Thank it worked. But can you explain me this code. What does it do?       private void NextActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                welcome myProg = new welcome();
                myProg.setTitle("Ceng 344 - Lab 7");
                myProg.setSize(450, 400);
                myProg.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                myProg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                myProg.setVisible(true);
            }

Comment: Ok, you need to add action to next button , when you click on it , it call another frame , so i create Next button **JButton next = new JButton("Next");** , then i add an action to it , this action called **NextActionPerformed** , this method  called the **Welcome** Frame

Comment: This part which you call it in **Welcome** Main method , so i don't need it in the main method , this is the **Next** button action

Comment: i think that you need to read in Java GUI , so try this : http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J4a_GUI.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all

1. You need to add `ActionListener` to the `JButton`
2. You can set the properties of `JFrame` inside constructor.
3. You don't need `main()` in `welcome.java`, only `constructor will do
   it.

Enter.java

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class Enter extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
public Enter(){
    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 20));
    add(new JLabel("Name"));
    add(new JTextField(8));
    add(new JLabel("Address"));
    add(new JTextField(15));
    add(new JLabel("Surname"));
    add(new JTextField(8));
    add(new JLabel("Phone"));
    add(new JTextField(8));
    JButton next = new JButton("Next");
    next.addActionListener(this);
    add(next);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    //if your frame contains more than one button then you can check which button is clicked using ae.getSource() or using ae.getActionCommand()
    new Welcome();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Enter myProg = new Enter();
    myProg.setTitle("Ceng 344 - Lab 7");
    myProg.setSize(450, 400);
    myProg.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    myProg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myProg.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

//Welcome

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
public class Welcome extends JFrame {
    public Welcome() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 20));
        add(new JLabel("Welcome"));
        setTitle("Ceng 344 - Lab 7");
        setSize(450, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1598040 if you edit in `Enter.java` then also it will work, but we don't need to implement `main()` in every java class. We just implement `main()` in starting class.

Comment: @user1598040 what error it is showing? it's working on my machine

Comment: @user1598040 may be you need to call `new welcome();` instead of `new Welcome();`, because your `welcome` java class starts will lowercase

Comment: it is showing error in next.addActionListener(this); and I tried Welcome and welcome

Comment: I dont know what the problem was but now its working. Thank you for your help

Comment: I found my mistake I forgot to implement ActionListener.

Comment: @Nachinne_Manche ok, and if this answer has help you to solve your issue, then you can accept it as answer

Comment: Thank you for your Help what should I do If I need to return from welcome.java to Enter.java by clicking Back Button